# Do I have to use weak_ptr.lock() just to test if it points to a valid object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

It seems kind of inefficient to have to create a temporary shared_ptr just to see if the weak_ptr is pointing to a valid object.  I don't want to even access the object.  This is because I have a function that returns a weak_ptr from a vector of shared_ptr and if it returns an empty weak_ptr then that means the object doesn't already exist with that GUID.

So I'm just testing if an object exists.

Is there another way to check to see if the weak_ptr is or isn't empty, without creating a shared_ptr?

Comment: How did you get the weak pointer in the first place?  _That's_ the interface that has to change.

Comment: lock() returns a shared_ptr which is why I made this post.

Comment: In the future use cppreference before asking.

Comment: @Mooing Duck what do you mean?  Your comment is vague.

Comment: In a multithreaded environment, it wouldn't be inefficient at all to make a temporary shared pointer. On the contrary, it would be absolutely necessary.

Comment: @EddieV223: Where did the `weak_ptr` come from?  I think whatever that is should also have given a flag saying if the `weak_ptr` was empty or not.

Comment: @Pubby I did, and I Read the MSDN as well.  Neither pages mention testing for empty, instead they say expired() tests if the manage object has been deleted.  Which is a different context than testing for a weak_ptr that never had anything in it.  But now that people have brought it to my attention it works.  Even the name expired() doesn't really explain the context that I'm using it for, but if it works it works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`expired()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired) member function.

Comment: @Pubby: I prefer using `if(someVector.empty())` over `if(someVecor.size()==0)`. Same reason I prefer `expired` in this case. More explicit

Comment: I hate to use Microsoft documentation unless it's a Microsoft specific function or question. Better would be http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired

Comment: @MarkRansom: Changed the link

Comment: @Pubby, see the note in the link: "`expired()` may be faster than `use_count()`."

Comment: I'm pretty sure `use_count` is documented to be for debugging purposes only due to performance concerns (`use_count() is not necessarily efficient. Use only for debugging and testing purposes, not for production code.`).